# If $0<x<y<z<\fracπ2,$ then find the range of $\frac{\sin x+\sin y+\sin z}{\cos x+\cos y+\cos z}.$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Sorry! This may appear an easy question for you but this is definitely not easy for me. Please suggest how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking $x,y,z$ very close, the thing is very close to $\tan x$, whose range is $[0,1]$. On the other hand, it's easy to show $0<\sin x < \cos x$ and so on. Therefore the answer is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Your comment is correct, except for the fact that the range of $\tan x$ is actually $[0, \infty]$.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, If I take $x=y-\varepsilon$ and $z=y+\varepsilon,$ then the expression equals(or tends to) $\color{blue}{\tan y}$ and for $0<y<\fracπ2,\;\tan y\in(0, \infty). $ Am I correct? (Actually here I have assumed that $x, y, z$ forms an AP with common difference $\varepsilon\to 0.$)

Comment: No, as $\theta\to\fracπ2,\;\tan \theta\to\infty.$ Or to be more specific at $\theta=\fracπ2,\;\tan \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}=\frac10,$ which is undefined. However, $\tan \fracπ4=1.$

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee Ah, yes. It's really stupid of me. Somehow I thought it's $\pi/4$. Then the answer is $(0, \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)= \frac{\sin x+\sin y+\sin z}{\cos x+\cos y+\cos z}$ and its range is
$$0=\lim_{z\to y\to x\to 0}f(x,y,z)< \frac{\sin x+\sin y+\sin z}{\cos x+\cos y+\cos z}
< \lim_{x\to y\to z\to \frac\pi2}f(x,y,z)=\infty
$$

Comment: Defined over $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: @Quanto, Okay, got it. Thanks.. I thought we could somehow simplify the expression but wasn't able to do so and hence posted it here. But your solution is vivid enough to understand what's actually happening here.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee - yeah, simplifying isn’t all that helpful